# how do i display the current week dates in salesforce?

Tags: salesforce

I am trying to display dates of current week. How can i do it? What i am trying to do is display the timesheet for the week.

So if i view the page today then it should display me the current week dates. Any pointers to approach this problem would be very helpful

Thanks

Prady

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think you could use the Date.toStartOfWeek function and then use addDays to that Date 7 times to determine the rest of the days of the week.

The reference is here:
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_date.htm